# How to designate a request param to bind to a certain controller method parameter instead of a model attribute in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, request

Here is a model class:

```
public class Contract{
   private Integer id;
   private String code;
}
```

Here is a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/generate-contract", method=GET)
public JsonResult generateContract(Contract contract, String code) throws Exception{
    //TODO
    return JsonResult.ok(data);
}
```

If I pass the parameter `id=1&code=DW23` to the method, how do I specify only the `contract`'s `code` property store the value or only the method parameter `code` store the value `DW23`?

Right now, from my experiment, both of them get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestParam` to map the request parameters to java variables. It also does the type conversion.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/generate-contract", method=GET)
public JsonResult generateContract(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String code) throws Exception{
    //TODO
    return JsonResult.ok(data);
}
```

The parameters can be made optional by specifying the `required` attribute of `@RequestParam`. e.g. `@RequestParam(value = "name", required=false) final String name` .With this, you will have to populate the properties of Contract manually by creating a new instance.